# How to download file to specific folder with DownloadManager(default) android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager

My project was made in Kotlin language. I am using `PRDownload library` to download files into my project with a `specific location`. But it is older and not updated now, so I thought that I will use `Default DOWNLOADMANAGER` to download files into my project.

`DOWNLOADMANGER` working fine and allowed me to download files, but it did not allow me to download files to a specific location in the Device.

I want to download file into this location.

> /data/data/com.music.video/files/mu/1/2.m4a

can someone help me to achieve this task?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you the author of the `com.music.video` app? If so, you could try using `FileManager` to get a `Uri` to that location and [use `setDestinationUri()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request#setDestinationUri(android.net.Uri)), but I am doubtful that it will work. You might need to download it yourself (e.g., using OkHttp). And, if you are not the author of `com.music.video`, then you have no write access to that location.